# Как создать пользовательский триггер на событие добавления сообщения в очередь SQS?

Tags: lambda, amazon, amazon-web-services

Я создал лямбда функцию. По умолчанию триггера для SQS нет. Решил пойти обходным путем и создал правило в `CloudWatch`, там выбрал следующее `Event Pattern` -> `Service Name: SQS`, `Event Type: All Events`. Добавил к правилу функцию лямбда и сохранил. К функции добавился триггер с этим правилом, но на события не реагирует. Помогите пожалуйста, как заставить работать лямбда функцию на события SQS ? Можно запустить с помощью планировщика `Cron` рас в минуту(минимальное время), но мне надо быстрее чтобы реагировал на события. Иначе нет смысла писать лямбда функцию в моем случае.

Comment: Поделитесь, как в итоге решили задачу?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov использовал вместо очередей `SNS`. Отравляю сообщение  в `SNS` и lambda моментально срабатывает.